# Looking for "portability oriented mobile application development" learning resource?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, portability

G'Day Developers,

I am about to hook my self into developing application for iOS platform, However my clients have no idea how to develop on iOS but they are familiar with Android and Windows mobile platform. So they insist me to develop their application in iOS in such a way that they can follow some of the fundamental ideas and start their project for Android and Windows later on.

**Long story short :** Is there any set of guidelines which can help me to produce design models and codes which later can be used in other platforms(...**not syntactically but semantically**...)?

Thank you for any input,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest way to do portable applications is to web applications (e.g. html5).

Then there are a number of packages on the market that allow you to access the hardware on the phone which you can use in your web application. These packages would then contain the device specific code allowing your application to stay portable.

Example of such a package is [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) but there are many more.

Comment: Thank you, Snecha is good and web could be my choice but I am not 100% sure that it would give me functionality to meet my client's requirement lol...However thanks this is the best way I should consider...